# How exactly can we style different <li>elements (within the same ul) separately?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am trying to clone the Apple website using just html and CSS for practice. I have not learnt any JavaScript yet. For the navigation bar, there would be mostly text links and one link which would be the apple logo.

Here's my code snippet:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background-color:whitesmoke;
}
nav{
    background-color: white;
    height: 45px;
}
nav ul{
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 33px;
}

.navtxt{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.logo{
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav>  
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home"><img class="logo" src="homelogo.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Store">Store</a></li>
        <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Mac">Mac</a></li>
        <li><a class="navtxt" href="#iPad">iPad</a></li>
        <li><a class="navtxt" href="iPhone">iPhone</a></li>
        <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Watch">Watch</a></li>
        <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Vision">Vision</a></li>
        <li><a class="navtxt" href="#AirPods">AirPods</a></li>
        <li><a class="navtxt" href="#TV & Home">TV & Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Entertainment">Entertainment</a></li>
        <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Accessories">Accessories</a></li>
        <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Support">Support</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

When I try to change the margins/padding (top) of the Apple logo image, even the text elements of the list end up moving downwards.

screenshot of the nav bar created:

[image]

When I increase the top margin for the image, even the text moves downwards:

screenshot after increasing margin-top to 12px:

[image]:

How can I style the image and text elements within the same list separately?

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to your problem. For example you could try to use Flexbox for aligning the nav content.

In the following snippet i set your `nav ul` to display flex, let Flexbox handle the alignment with `align-items` and `justify-content` and applied your 45px nav height here to give Flexbox enough space to do its thing. I also deleted some unnecessary styles.

(I used a font icon in the example, but it should work with your image the same way.)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 45px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 33px;
}

.navtxt {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.logo {
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Store">Store</a></li>
      <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Mac">Mac</a></li>
      <li><a class="navtxt" href="#iPad">iPad</a></li>
      <li><a class="navtxt" href="iPhone">iPhone</a></li>
      <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Watch">Watch</a></li>
      <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Vision">Vision</a></li>
      <li><a class="navtxt" href="#AirPods">AirPods</a></li>
      <li><a class="navtxt" href="#TV & Home">TV & Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Entertainment">Entertainment</a></li>
      <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Accessories">Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Support">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: I second that solution.
Do know that once the parent is a flex, all direct children will be automatically ignore any display that is inline and inline-block, so ''display: inline;'' in ''nav ul li'' is not needed.

Comment: how can I turn a flexbox container into a clickable link?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply styles to the first `<li>` like this:

```
nav>ul>li:first-child {...}
```

Or you can apply styles to any image in the list like this. I'd suggest that what you really need is to align the image with the centre line (middle) of the text, rather than the text baseline (the default).

```
nav>ul>li>img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```